# Append post title before publishing the wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to append my wordpress titles to have some static text in them before publishing. As my posts are directly posting to social media when they are published, I want this to happen before publishing.. I tried several approaches but none of them are working.
This does not work at all

```
function save_title( $title ){
        $text = '#ad #Myblog';
    $title = $title.$text;
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_title');
```

Below code works but just replace the whole title with static text and do not capture text I entered in post title manually when writing the post

```
function update_new_post_title( $data ) {
   $title = '#ad '.$_POST[ 'title' ];
    $data['post_title'] =  $title;
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'update_new_post_title' , '99', 1 );
```

I also tried `to_title` but that just update the title in wordpress. Not in the post before publishing.
Not sure if there is really a way to capture dynamic text entered in post and append. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/35993

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );

function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {
    // Change post title
    if (!strpos($data['post_title'], '_suffix')
        $data['post_title'] .= '_suffix';
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This does not work as it update it add the text multiple times whenever a post is updated or new

Comment: Just check if title contains text, and if not, append - see my edit

Comment: It still adds it twice.. As soon as I start a new post, it inserts it assuming there is no text in the field. It inserts it again when I click on publish button

Comment: I try to give you some references as I have no way of testing it, check the following link, they change slug but you could just adjust it to modify title https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105926/rewriting-post-slug-before-post-save